# convert a computed string to uint32_t without coping it into a char[] buffer in c

Tags: c

I am trying to convert a substring to integer but I am getting this output

```
    int main()
{
    char buf[50] = "210-567-12-2040-34567890.txt";
    char* pStart = buf;
    char* pCurrent = buf;
    while(*pCurrent != '\0')
    {
        if (*pCurrent == '-' || *pCurrent == '.') 
        {
            uint32_t val = strtoul(pStart, NULL, 10); 
            pStart = pCurrent+1;
            printf("%ul\n",val);
        }
        ++pCurrent;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am getting this output

```
210l                                                                                                                                   
567l                                                                                                                                   
12l                                                                                                                                    
2040l                                                                                                                                  
34567890l
```

Why is there a `l` in it?

Comment: Literally nothing in `buf` is a numeric value. `strtoul` won't work on it no matter what. What sort of end result are you expecting?

Comment: what wrong with `strtoul(pStart, NULL, 10);` ? Note that your code isn't not very clear.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the answers here are what you're looking for: [What is the difference between char s[] and char *s?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704407/what-is-the-difference-between-char-s-and-char-s)

Short answer is there's no difference between the two as a function argument. You can pass the `char* pStart` variable into `strtoul` the same as you'd pass the `char str[20]` variable into it. This will make it read the string directly from whatever memory address `pStart` points to, no need to copy into an array first.

Comment: But, I need to convert it upto "pCurrent - pStart", how do I do that?